# Замена содержимого в слайдере bxslider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Добрый день. Можно ли как-нибудь реализовать замену содержимого в слайдере [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) при нажатии ссылки?

Т.е. чтобы на странице слайдер выводил html содержимое одного файла, а при нажатии на ссылку - другого... и обратно - без перезагрузки страницы...